# Listen to a specific data attribute in events

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I need to listen to a `message` event that will have a `data` attribute and depending on this attribute do different actions.

```
window.addEventListener("message", m => {
    if m.data === "success" {
        console.log("Success!")
    } else {
        console.log("Failure!")
    }
});
```

Now, I want to test this with a button by dispatching such an event. However, I can only find the detail attribute, but not how to set the data attribute:

```
<button id="messageButton">Send Message</button>
```

and

```
messageButton.onclick = function () {
        messageButton.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("message", { bubbles: true, detail: "success" }))
}
```

How can I send with the `data` attribute instead of the `detail` attribute?

Comment: `m.detail` instead of `m.data`?

Comment: I don't see a `data` property in the specification of the `CustomEvent` class.

Comment: It's an external application which gives the information over the `data` attribute. So I can't change it. Maybe jQuery?

Comment: jQuery has its own event type that augments the native code.

Comment: @Barmar & Heikkisorsa - I'm guessing this is a message sent via [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage). `data` is a standard property on [`MessageEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessageEvent/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're testing a message event, you probably want [`MessageEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessageEvent/) rather than `CustomEvent`. `MessageEvent`'s constructor accepts an "init" object with a `data` property:

```
function sendMessage(data) {
    const event = new MessageEvent("message", { data });
    window.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

Example:

```js
window.addEventListener("message", m => {
    if (m.data === "success") {
        console.log("Success!");
    } else {
        console.log("Failure!");
    }
});

function sendMessage(data) {
    const event = new MessageEvent("message", { data });
    window.dispatchEvent(event);
}

document.getElementById("btnSuccess").addEventListener("click", function() {
    sendMessage("success");
});
document.getElementById("btnFailure").addEventListener("click", function() {
    sendMessage("failure");
});
```

```html
<button id="btnSuccess" type="button">Send 'success' Message</button> 
<button id="btnFailure" type="button">Send 'failure' Message</button>
```

But if you want to use `CustomEvent`, you'd create the event object, then add the property to it:

```
function sendMessage(data) {
    const event = new CustomEvent("message", { bubbles: true });
    event.data = data;
    window.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

Example:

```js
window.addEventListener("message", m => {
    if (m.data === "success") {
        console.log("Success!");
    } else {
        console.log("Failure!");
    }
});

function sendMessage(data) {
    const event = new CustomEvent("message", { bubbles: true });
    event.data = data;
    window.dispatchEvent(event);
}

document.getElementById("btnSuccess").addEventListener("click", function() {
    sendMessage("success");
});
document.getElementById("btnFailure").addEventListener("click", function() {
    sendMessage("failure");
});
```

```html
<button id="btnSuccess" type="button">Send 'success' Message</button> 
<button id="btnFailure" type="button">Send 'failure' Message</button>
```

Comment: Awesome! You're exactly right with the MessageEvent. Thank you!